# Can a single point in a manifold be seen as a sub manifold?

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology

In Pollack's differential topology, in Transversality, p.28, it reduced the study of the submanifold $Z$ to the simpler case, where $Z$ is a single point.
But by the definition of manifold, it seems that a single point is not a submanifold.

Comment: Why would a single point not be a manifold?

Comment: @SantiagoCanez, I think it can be a manifold, but not a submanifold, as it doesnt have an open set in the manifold( I mean the manifold contains $Z$) that contains this point.

Comment: @SantiagoCanez, could you explain how do you think about why a single point is sub manifold or even a manifold?

Comment: A 'connected' 0-dimensional manifold is *uniquely* classified as a point and a 'disconnected' 0-dimensional manifold is a discrete set (classified by its cardinality).

Comment: Because it is, by definition. There's not really much more to say. (A point is locally homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^0$.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a commenters said, a single point is a $0$-dimensional manifold. This is consistent with the fact that $\mathbb{R}^0=\{0\}$, and also with the fact that the boundary of a $d$-dimensional manifold-with-boundary is a $(d-1)$-dimensional manifold. (The boundary of $[0,1]$ is $\{0,1\}$.)

Since there is just one topology on a single-point space, it is always a submanifold whenever it's contained in another manifold: the restriction topology coming from the ambient space agrees with the intrinsic topology of the space.